# Forcing a video to fully loaded before playing

Tags: video, adobe-edge

I am creating my personal website with Adobe Edge's animate. Everything is great but one thing.

I have a video intro before entering the pages on the website. The preloader inside edge animate is assigned to "polite"; I want the video intro to be fully loaded before I play it so it will not buffer, even if this will take a longer time to load the whole thing.

Putting preloader as "polite" should do the trick, but it does not. It loads the website and when I click on the video to play, it's still buffering and lags! I tried the "Immediate" option too, but the same result.

Comment: May we see the code that you are using? You may wish to take with the language that you are using (JavaScript?) and any libraries too. What video format and player are you using? Please tag with those as well.

Comment: Thx Halfer for replying..

well, I am a graphic designer and not into developing and programming .. so I am letting edge animate do all the scripts .. I didn't edit any scripts .. suppose that "polite" thing do all I want .. but I think that I need to write something to work as I want ..

I am using mp4 - ogg - webm for formats

Comment: Ah, is this not a programming question at all? If so, you probably would be better off posting it on _Super User_.

Comment: actually edge animate lets you edit in with coding for things that need too .. that's why I am asking about a code or something that I can copy/paste it inside edge animate

it lets you deal with the html file that edge export .. I need some code or script to write it on the HTML file that fix this problem